# Maven install folder structure problem j2ee (spring, struts ..)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-2, struts

i'm using maven 2.1-SNAPSHOT as eclipse plugin.
My project structure is like this:

src/main/java
   -model
    -service
    -action
src/test/java
    empty atm
src/main/resources
    empty atm
src/test/resources
    empty atm
src/main/webapp
    -js
        -dojo
    -META-INF
    -WEB-INF
        web.xml 
        appcontext.xml
       struts.xml
    index.jsp

I'm having trouble understanding the build process and where to put which file.
I use as Application Server Jetty but i want to deploy my project on  tomcat as well
(so i have set up in my pom packaging war).

When i run my project with the maven:install command my target folder looks like this:
myproject.war
war
    not relevant
test-classes
    empty atm
myproject
    js
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
    index.jsp
classes
    model
    service
    action

My problem is that i need in the classes folder my persistence.xml which i have in META-INF. And struts.xml too i guess. I'm not sure about dojo either if it is right there. And honestly i don't know if this structure is right at all. I also dont know how to configure that the output changes.

I hope somebody can help me i really want to understand this process how it should be right, maybe there are even nice ressources to lookup to get
better at these things. Thanks in advance kukudas

Answer (score 2):

I believe files that you want deployed to the classpath go in the `resources/` folder.

Take a look at the [Maven in 5 Minutes guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), along with the [Getting Started](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the resources directory under the src/main/webapp directory. Thats where you can put in your properties and config files for hibernate, struts and spring.

That will allow Maven to copy the files over the the classes directory in the WAR.

Hope this helps.